# Find the volume of the solid $B$ given the bounds:

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

$B$ is a first octant solid bounded by $y=x^2$, $x=y^2$, and $x+y-z=-5$

Since first octant, we know that $x,y,z\geq 0$

We know $y=x^2$, and therefore, $x=y^2\to x=x^4(\text{ from $y=x^2$)}\to x=0,1$

Since $0\leq x\leq 1$, this means $0\leq y\leq 1$, which implies that $5\leq z\leq 7$ (by plugging in $(x,y)=(0,0)\text { and } (1,1)$

So the volume is:

$$\int^{1}_{0}dx\int^{1}_{0}dy\int^{7}_{5}dz=2$$

Is this correct? Usually your second and last integrals are functions of the other, not constant values exactly so I'm not sure.

Comment: On the second integral the bounds are of the form $y=?$ to $y=?$ where the equations are of the two parabolic boundaries. On the third integral the bounds are of the form $z=?$ to $z=?$ where the equations are for the two planar boundaries.

Comment: Nope, it's not correct. Your bounds just describe a rectangular box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to draw the solid:

[image]

Looking at the figure, it is easy to see that the integration will go from $0$ to $1$ with respect to $x$. If $x$ is given then the integration will go from $x^2$ to $\sqrt x$ with respect $y$. And, if $x$ and $y$ are given then the integration will go from $0$ to $x+y+5$. That is, the volume can be calculated as

$$\int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^{\sqrt x} \int_0^{x+y+5} 1\ dz\ dy \ dx.$$

Comment: Drawing the picture helps, thanks. I just wasn't sure of the plane so I didn't really draw it, but this helps. Can you just illustrate what the red line is for?

Comment: The thick red line is the integration domain when integrating with respect to $y $ at a given $x $.